# Create a clone of the object Array with my custom methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance

Is possible create a clone of the object Array? I do not want to extend the Array object itself because my specific methods should not be exposed for all the arrays of my app. Only a specific Arrays.

```
var Arr = function () {};
Arr.prototype = Object.create( Array.prototype );
Arr.prototype.push = function() {
    // Some custom code here
    Array.prototype.push.apply( this, arguments );
};
```

This example work well using methods, but if I set the values literally, the length is not incremented. Because Arr is an Object actually.

```
var arr1 = new Arr();
arr1[1] = 13;
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call( arr1 ), arr1, arr1.length); // [object Object] { '1': 13 } 0

var arr2 = new Array();
arr2[1] = 13;
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call( arr2 ), arr2, arr2.length); // [object Array] [ , 13 ] 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES5 and earlier, you couldn't "subclass" `Array` (that is, create your own constructor and prototype based on the `Array` constructor and `Array.prototype`) and get correct handling for the magic properties, but as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), it's possible in a couple of different ways, the easiest being the new `class` stuff:

```js
// REQUIRES ES2015+!
class MyArray extends Array {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }

    lengthTimesTwo() {
        return this.length * 2;
    }

    cappedJoin() {
        return this.map((s) => s.toUpperCase()).join();
    }
}

var a = new MyArray("one", "two", "three");
console.log("lengthTimesTwo: " + a.lengthTimesTwo());
console.log("cappedJoin: " + a.cappedJoin());
```

In the ES5 world, there are hoops you can jump through to get really close, and people building transpilers like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) do (if you're stuck targeting ES5 environments, you might want to use `class` and transpile), but most of the time it's good enough to create a function that builds an array and then adds methods just to that specific instance:

```js
var arrayExtras = {
  lengthTimesTwo: function() {
    return this.length * 2;
  },
  cappedJoin: function() {
      return this.map(function(s) {
        return s.toUpperCase();
      }).join();
    }
    //...and so on...
};

function myArray() {
  var key, rv = [];
  rv.push.apply(rv, arguments);
  for (key in arrayExtras) {
    Object.defineProperty(rv, key, { // Add the method as a non-enumerable property
        value: arrayExtras[key],
        writable: true
    });
    // For pre-ES5 support, change the call above to simply:
    // rv[ley] = arrayExtras[key];
  }
  return rv;
}

var a = myArray("one", "two", "three");
console.log("lengthTimesTwo: " + a.lengthTimesTwo());
console.log("cappedJoin: " + a.cappedJoin());
```